# Node-Red Editor and Library dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I'm in the process to create my first [Node-RED contribution](https://github.com/Stwissel/node-red-contrib-objectcleaner). The node will clean an incoming object based on a sample object provided in the editor. I'm using the `RED.editor` and the `RED.library`.

I'm wondering if I need to declare a dependency in my package file. Currently it looks like this:

```
{
    "name"         : "node-red-contrib-objectcleaner",
    "version"      : "0.0.1",
    "description"  : "Removes properties from incoming (payload) object, that are not in a template object",
    "dependencies": { /*Do I need anything here? */
    },
    "keywords": [ "node-red", "validation", "flow" ],
    "node-red"     : {
        "nodes": {
            "objectcleaner": "objectcleaner/objectcleaner.js"
        }
    }
}
```

What, if anything, goes into the dependencies? I know I will put node.js dependencies there, but do I need to list the editor/library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably do better asking questions like this on the mailing list here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red

You shouldn't need to list Node-RED in the dependencies as this will just pull in another copy into the node_modules tree.

You should be fine just using the reference to *RED* object that is passed in when the node is initialised